# How To Stub TypeScript Function Comments?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript, jsdoc

I'm running VS2013 and I'm just getting started with TypeScript.

I have Web Essentials 2013.5 and DocStubJs installed.  Currently when I'm writing my javascript, I use the C#-ish function comments auto created by DocStubJs:
[image]

I did this mainly because the DocStubJs stubbed out the Comments for me.  It (I'm assuming it's DocStubJS doing it) even works in TypeScript as well, and I just started using it since it was familiar and was what most of the code was in anyways.  But after looking at more documentation for Typescript, I see they use the JsDoc formatting:

```js
    /**
     * Does stuff
     *
     * @param blah stuff needing done
     */
    public doStuff(blah: string) {}
```

Which formatting should I use, the XML-ish commenting, or the DocJs?  If I go the DocJs route, is there anyway to be able to stub out the comments automagically?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 9/25/15**: the better JsDoc scaffolding is added to the TypeScript master today in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4978. If you feel adventurous you are welcome to clone the repo, [enable VS dev mode](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Dev-Mode-in-Visual-Studio), and use it today. :)

Go with the JsDoc route. The TypeScript team is adding support for JsDoc for the upcoming releases, which including the type information, intellisense and scaffolding. With [TS 1.6 beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-typescript-1-6-beta-react-jsx-better-error-checking-and-more.aspx), The scaffolding now works with `function`s. More support would likely be added in the future.

Comment: Too bad it sucks to have to hand roll it now.  Noticed that the Xml Version doesn't support method overloading

Answer (score 1):

Use JsDocs since XML Commenting doesn't work with intellisense for Method overloading in TypeScript

Also just figured out that typing `/**` will stub out the JsDoc Comments for you.